# CreateTruncOrBitCast or CreateAnd

Tags: llvm

I am using LLVM for code instrumentation, where each byte of a variable needs to be extracted. I have two alternatives:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  Value* cur_byte = CreateTruncOrBitCast(var, Int8Ty);
  cur_byte = IRB.CreateZExt(cur_byte, Int64Ty);
  /* do something */
  var = IRB.CreateLShr(var, 8);
}
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
  Value* cur_byte = CreateAnd(var, 0xFF);
  /* do something */
  var = IRB.CreateLShr(var, 8);
```

I would like to consult which method is faster, or is there any other better method?

Comment: You have to measure. Or not — Knuth would probably answer that the code that replaces the comment is the one that determines performance: until it exists, the code does not perform at all, neither slowly nor quickly.

Comment: Faster for what? It is an IR, not the final code for a specific CPU. There might be architectures where shifting is faster than logical and and other way around.